# This package can’t be installed. Error on Upgrading the Package

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, package, package-install

Iam trying to upgrade the package in destination org getting `This package can’t be installed.` error.

Below screenshot for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a package is uploaded, it has to be replicated ("published") to every server. This can take hours or even days, depending on how many packages have been uploaded recently. The solution is to wait until a later time and try installing again. You can also use the command line `sfdx force:package:install --publishwait -p packageName`, which can do the waiting for you.

Comment: THe command line need to execute on source Org or Destination Org

Comment: @user3214361 The destination org.